# Selecting photo id, small_src from a certain album

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I would like to get the ids and thumbnail image sources of pictures belonging to a certain album.
I have the user_photos permission and the album_id is that of the app_user.

So far, I have tried:
`https://graph.facebook.com/<album_id>?fields=photo&access_token=...`
^Returns too much data like comments and tags and whatnot. I'd like to avoid that.

And FQL:
  `SELECT pid,src_small FROM photo WHERE aid="album_id"`

url:
    `https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+pid,src_small+FROM+photo+WHERE+aid="    <album_id>"&access_token=...`
Gets an empty result.

I'm planning to write an ajax photo-selector to work with my app :(

Comment: Ah, I've fixed the FQL query. I should have used the album_object_id instead of aid in the FQL query. Any advice is still appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/

"src_small" -> The URL to the thumbnail version of the photo being queried. The image can have a maximum width of 75px and a maximum height of 225px. **This URL may be blank.**

Maybe you can try "images" instead.

For example,

```
SELECT pid,images FROM photo WHERE aid="album_id"
```

Then select one url by size range of the photo you need.